# What exactly the Ellipsoid method does?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, convex-hulls

Recently, I'm studying an algorithm in Optimization, the Ellipsoid method or algorithm. With this method you can find(In polynomial time) a feasible solution of a linear program, or more precise can find a point in a polyhedron which we know the inequalities of the polyhedron.

But I want to know we can use this method to find an optimal solution or not?

I appreciate any help of you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it to determine if a certain value is attainable or not, and thus guess the optimal value. Suppose the problem is $\max(c^T x : Ax \leq b, x \geq 0)$. We can check if $(c^T x \geq \mbox{guess}, Ax \leq b, x \geq 0)$ is feasible and if so which point that is. You can then do binary search to converge onto an optimal solution

Comment: Chvatal's *Linear Programming* has a chapter on the ellipsoid method with enough detail that one could easily implement this.  It's hopeless in practice for problems of any significant size, but you can actually solve small LP's using this approach.

Comment: @david-lui What do you mean by binary search? could you please introduce some reference which explain this binary search?

Comment: @BrianBorchers In Chvatal's book with ellipsoid method we can find the optimal solution? or just a point in polyhedron?

Comment: I believe (haven't looked at it in years) that Chvatal discusses the binary search aspect.  It's really quite simple though.  Starting with a feasible solution (obtained by the ellipsoid algorithm) with known objective value, you've got a lower bound, $L$,  on the optimal objective.  Pick a much large value $U$, and see if the problem is feasible with $c^{T}x\geq U$.  If not, then you have an upper bound.  Keep halving the distance between $L$ and $U$ ($M=(L+U)/2)$) and testing whether it's feasible with $c^{T}x\geq M$.

Comment: Wouldn't finding a dual feasible value get an upper bound in a much easier way?